# Twitch streaming via Linux

Tags: video-streaming

I'm currently working on a small project.
3 colleagues and I want to stream separately on Twitch, but we also want to combine all 4 streams (the way we stream to Twitch) into one stream. It should simply switch from one stream to another every minute.
Is there a way to accomplish this using Linux in some form?

Comment: Could you maybe use OBS somehow? I’d see if that would meet your needs. Not sure if OBS can be scripted though